# NamingException after lookup for EntityManager

Tags: java, jpa, weblogic, entitymanager, naming

When I try to get an Entitymanager, I become always a NamingException.. Here's the point where it crashes: (in the lookup function)

```
try {
      ctx = new InitialContext();
      entityManager = (EntityManager)ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/myExample");
    } catch (NamingException namingException) {
      throw new NamingException();
    }
```

My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="myExample">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <jta-data-source>DSLDB</jta-data-source>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/interface_orm.xml</mapping-file>

        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.UpdateManager" value="operation-order" />
            <property name="openjpa.FlushBeforeQueries" value="false" />
            <property name="openjpa.OrphanedKeyAction" value="none" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionRetainMode" value="transaction" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="useNativeSequenceCache=true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The persistence.xml is located under the lib component in a META-INF folder.

I have also defined the datasource in my deploy.xml:

```
<datasource database="oracle">
            <jndi_id value="DSLDB"/>

            <user value="user"/>
<!--            <user value="user1"/> -->

            <password value="password"/>

            <jdbc_url value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//skjdfhsdhf2009-skip.moage.org:1522/WKFISAS.nittaschoa.net"/> <!-- JAP7 IT -->

            <transaction_protocol value="EmulateTwoPhaseCommit" />
            <!--
            <driver_class value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
            <support_xa_transaction value="true" />
            <transaction_protocol value="None" />
            <test_table value=" SQL SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" />
            -->
        </datasource>
```

Comment: entityManager = (EntityManager)ctx.lookup("myExample"); try this

Comment: See the edited answer and talk

Comment: what do you mean with bound to jndi? how does this work? @Shahzeb

Comment: In weblogic you do not need `java:/comp/env/` like Prasanna Kumar H A mentioned. You can go direct to the JNDI name. What is the stack trace?

Comment: Hi @DisplayNameismissing 
Thanks for your answer! Now I got another error.... 
Stacktrace:
java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource cannot be cast to javax.persistence.EntityManager
        at com.csg.cs.jap.tutorial.ubs.lib.EntityManagerFinder.getEntityManager(EntityManagerFinder.java:60)